# Relaxing Binary Variable on Cplex

Tags: cplex, opl

I need help. I have coded my model on CPLEX and now I want to solve the same problem by changıng one of the binary variables to float for a certain period. Let me give you an example, for 10 time perıods, for the first two periods the variable is binary but for the last 8 perıods it will be continous (relaxed). I am trying to solve it opl flow control but I have some problems with the variable conversion. I will be very happy , if you can help me

Thank you ın advance

Answer (score 0):

```
dvar float x[1..5] in 0..9.2;
    

    dvar int intx[1..5];
    


    maximize sum(i in 1..5) x[i];
    subject to
    {
    forall(i in 1..5)ctx:intx[i]-x[i]==0;
    

    }

    execute
    {
    writeln("x  : ",x);
    }

    main
    {
    writeln("solve model");

    thisOplModel.generate();
    cplex.solve();
    thisOplModel.postProcess();

    writeln("relax integrity constraint on x for 1 and 2 and solve model");
    cplex.setLb(thisOplModel.ctx[1],-Infinity);
    cplex.setLb(thisOplModel.ctx[2],-Infinity);
    
    cplex.solve();
    thisOplModel.postProcess();

    writeln("put back integrity constraint on x and solve model");
    cplex.setLb(thisOplModel.ctx[1],0);
    cplex.setUb(thisOplModel.ctx[2],0);
    cplex.solve();
    thisOplModel.postProcess();
    }
```

gives

```
solve model
x  :  [9 9 9 9 9]
relax integrity constraint on x for 1 and 2 and solve model
x  :  [9.2 9.2 9 9 9]
put back integrity constraint on x and solve model
x  :  [9 9.2 9 9 9]
```